# rust mutex borrowed value does not live long enough

Tags: rust

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy3zt.png)

I want lock multiple page before executor action ,how do?

Comment: Please do not use images for code or errors. It makes it difficult to reference your question and image links may break preventing future viewers from understanding your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from the code it looks like it's possible to hit the same entry multiple times. This means you'll immediately deadlock, as the second access will try to lock a mutex which is already locked. You should probably use `or_insert_with` in order to only acquire the lock if there was no entry for that key.

Second, well `MutexGuard` (whether that of tokio or the stdlib) borrows the mutex. Since the Mutex is only borrowed for the span of the iteration, the MutexGuard can't outlive that. The way to fix that is to expand the Mutex's lifetime e.g. by adding it to a collection that's outside the iteration then borrowing *that*. At which point you probably need *two* iterations, because if you push a lock into the "owner" collection then immediately borrow that, the collection will be borrowed on the next iteration and you won't be able to insert a new item:

```rust
    let mut locks = vec![];
    let mut page_map = HashMap::new();
    for key in keys {
        let page = store.get(key).unwrap();
        locks.push((key, page.clone()));
    }
    for (key, lock) in &locks {
        page_map.entry(key).or_insert_with(|| lock.lock());
    }
```

Although then you're hitting the third issue (and second likelyhood of deadlock): if this can be executed twice concurrently it's possible for two calls to have `key_feature_map` in different order, meaning one call might lock page A then try to acquire page B, while a second call will have locked page B and now try to acquire page A.

Both calls are waiting on the other's lock, so they'll be deadlocked.

Comment: third issue :  order page